# how to hide database information on view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when I attempt to run my code, I got the error above.

As you can see on the following image, the page posts/index leaves appear some information before the footer of the page :

[image]

I don't understand where it may come, because it's the only page where it appeared.

Here's my view :

```
<%= @post.each do |post| %>
<h1 class="Blog_post_title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h1>
<p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></p>
<p><%= image_tag post.landing_image.url , class: "landing_image_blog"  %></p>
<p><%= post.body %></p>
<%= link_to post do %>
<div class="button12">Continuer la lecture</div>
<% end %>
<div class="border_grey_blog"></div>
<% end %>
</div>
<%= render "footer" %>
```

my posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @post = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title,:title2,:title3,:title4,:title5,:title6,:title7,:title8,:title9, :body, :image,:image1,:image2,:image3,:image4,:image5,:image6,:image7,:image8, :landing_image, :some_text1, :some_text2, :some_text3, :some_text4, :some_text5, :some_text6, :some_text7, :some_text8, :some_text9, :some_text0))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end


def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to "/posts"
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image,:image1,:image2,:image3,:image4,:image5,:image6,:image7,:image8, :landing_image, :some_text1, :some_text2, :some_text3, :some_text4, :some_text5, :some_text6, :some_text7, :some_text8, :some_text9, :some_text0, :title2,:title3,:title4,:title5,:title6,:title7,:title8,:title9)
end
end
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your outputting the result of @posts.each. Notice how you did this in your view:

```
<%= @post.each do |post| %>
  # other code
<% end %>
```

This will actually output all the data in the array as a ruby object. If you want to change this to not output everything, you need to change it to

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
  # other code
<% end %>
```

This will now not return the @post.each in the html.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is in the very first line of the view:

```
<%= @post.each do |post| %>
```

should be

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
```

since `<%=` opens an expression tag that will display its content.